# kdb/Q How to Union Join two tables, summing a specific value?

Tags: join, kdb

I have two tables:

info

| First | Last | Score | Full Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ann | R | 10 | Ann R |
| Bob | C | 12 | Bob C |
| Ann | R | 13 | Ann R |
| Fil | B | 19 | Fil B |

summary

| Full Name | Sum_Scores |
| --- | --- |
| Ann R | 23 |
| Fil B | 19 |
| Bob C | 12 |

The summary table lists all unique Full Name items and orders by the sum of the values in the Score column.

I am wondering how to do this, I have the Full Name column in the summary table, but not sure how I can populate the Sum_Scores field:

summary -> current version

| Full Name | Sum_Scores |
| --- | --- |
| Ann R |  |
| Bob C |  |
| Fil B |  |

I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understand but:

```
q)t:([]score:10 12 13 19;FullName:`$("Ann R";"Bob C";"Ann R";"Fil B"))
q)`score xdesc select sum score by FullName from t
FullName| score
--------| -----
Ann R   | 23
Fil B   | 19
Bob C   | 12
```

Does this alone not give you what you need? Why do you already have a second table with FullNames? Unless the table you already have serves as a filter in which case you could do

```
q)t2:([]FullName:`$("Ann R";"Fil B"))
q)`score xdesc select sum score by FullName from t where FullName in t2`FullName
FullName| score
--------| -----
Ann R   | 23
Fil B   | 19
```

Comment: I guess you're right about not needing the second table. It looks like the first option works great, thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Terry's second solution, you can also achieve it using:

```
q)t2#select sum score by FullName from t
FullName| score
--------| -----
Ann R   | 23
Fil B   | 19
```

Comment: Thank you (and Terry) for answering my q questions!